# Populating each calendar month with a specific incrementing pattern

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas `DataFrame` indexed by a timeseries, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.date_range('2023-01-01', '2023-12-31', freq='1D')
pd.DataFrame({'a' : np.random.randint(0, 10, len(index))}, index=index)
```

```
            a
2023-01-01  3
2023-01-02  2
2023-01-03  1
2023-01-04  3
2023-01-05  8
...        ..
2023-12-27  2
2023-12-28  2
2023-12-29  0
2023-12-30  1
2023-12-31  7
```

How can I add a new column populated with an incrementing pattern within each calendar month? E.g. `b = day_of_month / days_in_month`

```
            a         b
2023-01-01  0  0.032258
2023-01-02  5  0.064516
2023-01-03  2  0.096774
2023-01-04  7  0.129032
2023-01-05  4  0.161290
...        ..       ...
2023-12-27  6  0.870968
2023-12-28  5  0.903226
2023-12-29  8  0.935484
2023-12-30  2  0.967742
2023-12-31  9  1.000000
```

Such that the following pattern is created:

[image]

Comment: I have encountered many questions and answers pertaining to populating a `DataFrame` column with an incrementing pattern on a fixed interval, but none which address the varying length of calendar months or `DatetimeIndex` indicies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit convoluted, but this can be accomplished using the following procedure:

1. Assign the day of month to a new column.

```
df['b'] = df.index.day
```

```
            a   b
2023-01-01  3   1
2023-01-02  0   2
2023-01-03  0   3
2023-01-04  8   4
2023-01-05  2   5
...        ..  ..
2023-12-27  2  27
2023-12-28  1  28
2023-12-29  3  29
2023-12-30  1  30
2023-12-31  4  31
```

2. Assign the last day of a monthly resample to a third column. This will ensure index unity.

```
df['c'] = df.resample('1M').b.last().copy()
```

```
            a   b     c
2023-01-01  3   1   NaN
2023-01-02  0   2   NaN
2023-01-03  0   3   NaN
2023-01-04  8   4   NaN
2023-01-05  2   5   NaN
...        ..  ..   ...
2023-12-27  2  27   NaN
2023-12-28  1  28   NaN
2023-12-29  3  29   NaN
2023-12-30  1  30   NaN
2023-12-31  4  31  31.0
```

3. Back-fill and apply operations (in the asked case, division).
4. (optional) Dispose of the helper column, `c`.

```
            a         b
2023-01-01  3  0.032258
2023-01-02  0  0.064516
2023-01-03  0  0.096774
2023-01-04  8  0.129032
2023-01-05  2  0.161290
...        ..       ...
2023-12-27  2  0.870968
2023-12-28  1  0.903226
2023-12-29  3  0.935484
2023-12-30  1  0.967742
2023-12-31  4  1.000000
```

A complete example, extending the code from the question:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.date_range('2023-01-01', '2023-12-31', freq='1D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : np.random.randint(0, 10, len(index))}, index=index)

df['b'] = df.index.day
df['c'] = df.resample('1M').b.last().copy()
df.c = df.c.bfill()
df.b /= df.c
df.drop(['c'], inplace=True, axis=1)
```